# Entity Framework, Unneeded Foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF Code first.

I created two classes. For simplicity, imagine that I have a User table (class) and a FileAttachment table. I want to use the FileAttachment table with many other classes, so that any part of the application that requires having a FileAttachment can reuse that table. The problem is that when EF generates the schema, it creates a Foreign Key in the FileAttachment table back to User table. Is there a way to disable that?

Thanks

Comment: What do your entities look like?

Comment: User = UserId, UserName, ICollection<FileAttachment>.

FileAttachment = FileId, ByteRepresentation, UserId (Unwanted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build an intermediate class.

```
public class UserDocument
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public virtual User User {get;set;}

    public int FileAttachmentId {get;set;}
    public virtual FileAttachment FileAttachment {get;set;}
}
```

So your user class can now have:

```
public virtual ICollection<UserDocument> Documents {get;set;}
```

And in this case, FileAttachment class will not have reference to User.

If you want now to build some other document type, just implement another intermediate type, i.e. imagine you want to have CustomerDocument:

```
public class CustomerDocument
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public virtual Customer Customer {get;set;}

    public int FileAttachmentId {get;set;}
    public virtual FileAttachment FileAttachment {get;set;}
}
```

And then your hypothetical Customer class would have:

```
public virtual ICollection<CustomerDocument> Documents {get;set;}
```

Comment: certainly works, but seems overkill... I don't know if this is a limitation of EF or if this is how my schema should be designed.

Comment: It is not overkill, this is how you tie your reusable class with other classes. There is no other way as far as I know, and if you try to draw relationships on paper, both your way and with this approach, you'll see that this is completely logical :)